# Convert the JSON response from Alamofire POST to a variable that can display

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to get a response from a server.
Here are the codes I use:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "pic", fileName: "filename.png", mimeType: "image/png")

        }, to: "http://cse-jcui-08.unl.edu:8910/image",
           method: .post,
           encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseString { response in
                    debugPrint(response)



                    }

                case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                }
```

Here are the responses I got:
[image: json response]

my question is, how can I save the name and value as a variable, so that I can display it on my app?
The way I am doing it, I actually try several times on SwiftyJSON,

like this :

```
struct Food {

                        var name: String
                        var value: String

                        init(name: String, value: String) {
                            self.name = name
                            self.value = value
                        }
                    }

                    let json = response.result.value
                    let name = json!["name"]
```

But it gives me an error like this ：Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'

So, would anyone pleased to help me with this?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire doesn't automatically parse the `response.result.value` (value is still a serialized JSON string). Since you mentioned SwiftyJSON, try parsing the value with SwiftyJSON's `JSON(jsonString)` function.

```
/** Parse the string with SwiftyJSON */
let json = JSON(response.result.value)
let name = json["name"]

/** Parse Predictions arrayValue */
for row in json["predictions"].arrayValue {
    let name = row["name"].string
    let value = row["value"].double
    print("Prediction for \(name) is \(value)")
}
```

Not sure this is the only problem, but it's a start.

Comment: hey, I just tried,     if I just use let json = JSON(response.result.value as Any)
                    
                        print(json)       I got something back.  But when I trying to use let prediction = json ["prediction"]  print (prediction), I got a null. Any thoughts on that ?   thanks in advance.

Comment: Prediction looks like a nested array. I've updated the answer to show you parsing it to an arrayValue then looping it's values.

Comment: hi man, I have tried it too. And it gives me nothing. It gives me a warning of String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value

Comment: In my example above, what do you get when you do something like `print(type(of: json))` and `print(json)`? A string interpolation warning sounds like the `response.result.value` or the predictions sub key still isn't properly parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of native JSON parsing using `Codable` protocol in Swift 4:

```
// Struct inheriting Codable protocol
struct Food: Codable {
    var name: String
    var value: Double
}
struct Prediction: Codable {
    var foods: [Food]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case foods = "prediction"
    }
}

// SAMPLE DATA BEGIN, Use alamofire response instead
let string = """
{"prediction":[
{"name":"marshmallow","value":0.2800},
{"name":"caesar salad","value":0.0906},
{"name":"egg","value":0.0748},
{"name":"apple","value":0.0492},
{"name":"chickpea","value":0.0469}
]}
"""
let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
```

Usage:

```
let foods = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Prediction.self, from: string.data(using: .utf8)!).foods

print(foods[0].name)  // marshmallow
print(foods[0].value) // 0.28
```

Note: `Codable` makes SwiftyJSON as parser obsolete.

Comment: since the json will be different everytime I post, so how can I change the string? should I change it to let string = reponse.result.value ?

Comment: You dont have to use above string, its just for example, instead use `response.data` alamofire response, like so `let foods = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: response.data!).prediction`